# libvirt: how to pass qemu command-line args now libvirt schemas is 404

Tags: qemu, libvirt, virt-manager

This is the only way I have found to pass arguments to qemu:

```
<domain type='qemu' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
```

Unfortunately the url http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0 now simply returns a 404 page, and libvirt automatically trims this part off. I can't seem to find any information on an alternative as even the libvirt website advises adding this broken schema!

Is there is another way to enable evdev pass-though without qemu arguments?

EDIT:

I solved this using the solution marked below, but one important thing to note is that virsh will always trim off `xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'` *unless* there is a valid `<qemu:[whatever]>` tag somewhere in the domain.

Comment: No, that post is outdated, the virsh import functionality has since been deprecated and does not work for this purpose, another solution posted there is exactly where I run into the problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the URL of the namespace is a 404, using it in a domain configuration does work, and is documented on the [`libvirt` homepage](https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#qemucommand):

> Additionally, the following XML additions allow fine-tuning of the command line given to `qemu` when starting a domain (Since 0.8.3). In order to use the XML additions, it is necessary to issue an XML namespace request (the special `xmlns:name` attribute) that pulls in http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0; typically, the namespace is given the name of `qemu`. With the namespace in place, it is then possible to add an element `<qemu:commandline>` under domain, with the following sub-elements repeated as often as needed:
>
> `qemu:arg`
>
> Add an additional command-line argument to the `qemu` process when starting the domain, given by the value of the attribute value.
>
> `qemu:env`
>
> Add an additional environment variable to the `qemu` process when starting the domain, given with the name-value pair recorded in the attributes name and optional value.

This is also tested in various places in `libvirt`:

- https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/0279a51b83e3711c3766cb9503becab3813dee95/tests/qemuxml2argvdata/qemu-ns-no-env.xml
- https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/0279a51b83e3711c3766cb9503becab3813dee95/tests/qemuxml2argvdata/qemu-ns-commandline.xml
- https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/0279a51b83e3711c3766cb9503becab3813dee95/tests/qemuxml2argvdata/qemu-ns.xml
- and others

I tested [this solution](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/0279a51b83e3711c3766cb9503becab3813dee95/tests/qemuxml2argvdata/qemu-ns-no-env.xml) on a kvm domain by changing the beginning of the definition to

```xml
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-unknown'/>
    <qemu:arg value='parameter'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
```

in `virsh -c qemu:///system edit <domain>`. On subsequent edits, those changes still exist (the new elements are moved to the end of the document, though).

Starting the domain also fails with `qemu` complaining about an unknown parameter:

```
↪ virsh -c qemu:///system start <domain>
error: Failed to start domain <domain>
error: Interner Fehler: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -unknown: invalid option
```

Note that an XML namespace [does not need to be a URL that resolves to something ... usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613891/must-an-xml-namespace-name-uri-be-retrievable).

Comment: in my case I was trying *https* and it was not working